# Get last day of the year using Date int swift?

Tags: swift, date, swift3

I want to get the las day of the current year, I need this to change with time so if I use this function in 2018 I get as last day 31 of December 2018 but if I use the function right now it should give me 31 December 2017. I know I can get the current date by just using

```
var current = Date()
```

And I know that I can get for example this same day one year from now that should be approximately

```
 var dayComponents = DateComponents()
        dayComponents.day = 365
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        if let lastDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dayComponents, to: Date()) {
            return lastDate
        } else {
            return Date()
        }
```

The problem is that I need just from now to the end of the year, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would get the current year component of the current date. Add one to get next year. Then use that to get the 1st day of that year. Then subtract 1 day to get the last day of the current year.

```
// Get the current year
let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
// Get the first day of next year
if let firstOfNextYear = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year + 1, month: 1, day: 1)) {
    // Get the last day of the current year
    let lastOfYear = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: firstOfNextYear)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also try like this get first day of current year add 1 year and subtract 1 day.

```
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date())
if let startDateOfYear = Calendar.current.date(from: components) {
    components.year = 1
    components.day = -1
    let lastDateOfYear = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startDateOfYear)
}
```