# Swift: Calendar nextDate always returns nil if trying to match year component

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

I was trying to find a robust way of getting the end of the current year in Swift and tried this:

```
let yearComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date.now)
return Calendar.current.nextDate(
    after: Date.now,
    matching: yearComponent,
    matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
    repeatedTimePolicy: .last,
    direction: .forward
)
```

To my surprise, this always returns `nil`. I'm trying to understand why. While, depending on the precision required, there might be simpler solutions, I'm interested in why this solution does not work and if there is a better/working solution that returns the last possible moment of the current year.

Comment: Why don’t you simply add 1 to the year component?

Comment: Note that you are trying to match the year after now which should be the same as now. Do you have an idea how many matches that would result from this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321586/get-last-day-of-the-year-using-date-int-swift?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C61.7080 to get the last day of the current year. For you, just subtract 1 second instead of 1 day to get the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what is the exact implementation of this nextDate method (unless it's code is available somewhere) but theoretically there is infinite amount of dates after Date.now with current year so I guess that perhaps it might be implemented in such way that it always increases given component at least once (and starts searching from first possible date after this increase) and only after that it checks if proper date was found and this is the reason why it does not find any date in your case.

Anyway you could do something like in the code below to get the last second of the current year so maybe this will be enough for your needs:

```
let yearComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date.now)
let yearStart = Calendar.current.date(from: yearComponent)
let nextYearStart = yearStart.flatMap({ Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: $0) })
let yearEnd = nextYearStart?.addingTimeInterval(-1)
print("yearEnd = \(yearEnd)")
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but "last possible moment" is hard to define as again theoretically it can have infinite precision so probably you should just use nextYearStart from above example and compare other dates with that.

Comment: thanks! this is pretty much what I do now. 

You are right that "last possible moment" is not clearly defined, but I think the iOS Calendar has a certain precision (nanoseconds I suppose?) so I would have assumed `nextDate` would return the last nanosecond of the year. I'm not trying to achieve something specific here, this was a question out of curiosity ("why does this method not work as I expect?"), I don't think there is any real-world case where I would need such a high precision :-)